# Hibernate/jpql comparing strings with varied lenght using > < operators to find a range of entites

Tags: string, hibernate, compare, jpql

First time writer.

My question is how is it possble to do this query:

```
Select client from Client client where client.zipcode is > ?1 and client.zipcode<?2
```

given that 
client.Zipcode contains letters and numbers and so does the parameters in varied lenght

so that param 1 = 100 and param 2 = 1000
will find a client with client.zipcode ="ab 200"

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the text part from the `zipcode` before casting it to a number.

```
select client from Client client where 
CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING(client.zipcode, LOCATE(' ', client.zipcode)+1)) AS float) > ?1
and 
CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING(client.zipcode, LOCATE(' ', client.zipcode)+1)) AS float) < ?2
```

Comment: My bad i should have given more examles

it could also have been any combination of letters, spaces and numbers

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing was 
padding my parameter with  0es in front then substringed it to be 16 in lenght

and i did the same in my query

```
 substring('0000000000000000'+coalesce(client.zipcodee),LENGTH(coalesce(client. 
 zipcode)+1,16)<=?1
```

so now  it can compare the strings because they are equal lenght